# In a competition of $45$ people, how many received medals in exactly two categories?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

### Background

I've been learning the basics of set theory and this is a reference to [*Business Mathematics and Statistics*](https://books.google.ie/books?id=qkSlDwAAQBAJ&pg=SA2-PA56&lpg=SA2-PA56&dq=In+a+competition,+a+school+awarded+medals+in+different+categories.+36+medals+in+dance,+12+medals+in+dramatics+and+18+medals+in+music.+If+these+medals+went+to+a+total+of+45+people+and+only+4+people+got+medals+in+all+the+three+categories,+how+many+received+medals+in+exactly+two+of+these+categories?&source=bl&ots=np0Zgv42z0&sig=ACfU3U2dX0-RtWBspE1fAx4DLNZV2zZfug&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXtKf_m4bvAhXVRxUIHTT7Dcc4ChDoATAHegQICBAD#v=onepage&q=In%20a%20competition%2C%20a%20school%20awarded%20medals%20in%20different%20categories.%2036%20medals%20in%20dance%2C%2012%20medals%20in%20dramatics%20and%2018%20medals%20in%20music.%20If%20these%20medals%20went%20to%20a%20total%20of%2045%20people%20and%20only%204%20people%20got%20medals%20in%20all%20the%20three%20categories%2C%20how%20many%20received%20medals%20in%20exactly%20two%20of%20these%20categories%3F&f=false)
by Asim Kumar Manna, section 2.56:

> In a competition, a school awarded medals in different categories. $36$
> medals in dance, $12$ medals in dramatics and $18$ medals in music. If
> these medals went to a total of $45$ people and only $4$ people got
> medals in all the three categories, how many received medals in
> exactly two of these categories?

### My attempt

[image]

Let $A$ = set of persons who got medals in dance.
$B$ = set of persons who got medals in dramatics.
$C$ = set of persons who got medals in music.

Given,

$n(A) = 36$
$n(B) = 12$
$n(C) = 18$
$n(A \cup B \cup C) = 45$
$n(A \cap B \cap C) = 4$

We know that number of elements belonging to exactly two of the three sets $A, B, C$

$= n(A \cap B) + n(B \cap C) + n(A \cap C) - 3n(A \cap B \cap C)$
$= n(A \cap B) + n(B \cap C) + n(A \cap C) - 3 \times 4 \dots(i)$
$=n(A \cup B \cup C) = n(A) + n(B) + n(C) - n(A \cap B) - n(B \cap C) - n(A \cap C) + n(A \cap B \cap C)$

Therefore

$n(A \cap B) + n(B \cap C) + n(A \cap C) = n(A) + n(B) + n(C) + n(A \cap B \cap C) - n(A \cup B \cup C)$

From $(i)$ required number

$= n(A) + n(B) + n(C) + n(A\cap B \cap C) - n(A \cup B \cup C) - 12$
$= 36 + 12 + 18 + 4 - 45 - 12$
$= \boxed{13}$

13 medals received. Is there a better way go about this? Is this process succinct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your set analysis seems solid. There's a minor shortcut available since we know the total winning population is being overcounted by the category medal counts due to those who won multiple medals.

Given total medals of $36+12+18=66$, we know we could also express this total medal count as  $M_1 + 2M_2 + 3M_3 = 66$, where $M_i$ is the number of people who won $i$ medals.

Then we also know that the number of medal winners $M_1 + M_2 + M_3 = 45$,

So subtracting, $M_2+2M_3 = 21$ and of course $M_3 = 4$ giving the consistent result $M_2 = 13$

Answer (score 1):

In words

- There were $36+12+18 =66$ medals
- $45$ teams won at least one
- leaving $66-45=21$ extra medals
- of which $4\times(3-1)=8$ were extra medals for teams winning three matches
- leaving $21-8=13$ extra medals for teams winning two matches
- so there were $13$ teams winning exactly two matches

As equations, if $m_1$ teams won one medal, $m_2$ teams won two medals and $m_3$ teams won three medals then

- $m_1+m_2+m_3 = 45$
- $m_1+2m_2+3m_3=36+12+18$
- $m_3=4$

which are three linear equations in three unknowns, with the unique solution $m_1=28, m_2=13, m_3=4$ and the question asks for $m_2$